# Interactive map solutions that support overlapping polygons - stand alone or web based

Tags: polygon, cartography, software-recommendations, overlapping-features

I need to make an interactive map (stand alone or web based) where users click on an area and it shows the polygon area and the attributes associated with GIS polygons. My users do not have access to GIS so I can't email them the GIS table. Users need to be able to zoom in and out, pan and see a base map but there doesn't need any more sophisticated functionality.

Some of the polygons in my GIS table overlap. If there are two polygons A and B, the overlapping area is C. I want users to click on area C and see the separate attributes for both A and B (not a sum of A and B added together).

What interactive maps support overlapping polygons? Instant Atlas and Google My Maps do not.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can publish your polygons as a map (web) service, you could use the [IdentifyTask](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/identifytask-amd.html) in Esri's javascript api.  In [this sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/find_popup.html), if you click on a house, it gives access to both the house polygon and the parcel polygon it falls within.